# How can I get the wikipedia page of a Google Maps POI?

Tags: google-maps, wikipedia-api

I used the wiki query api but unfortunately doesn't work with all the places because Wikipedia use different names.

Example: Google maps = Monte Viso,
         Wikipedia = Monviso

Comment: You cannot expect two different service to have the same keys... I guess you could look for a search engine rather than api (to use synonyms) but not sure that a such a tool exist

Comment: Obviously I know but I was searching for a way to connect them

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation of the two APIs you are talking about? Or an example of the API calls involved that have the two different names?

Comment: Google Maps Android Api (more specifically, the POI) = https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/poi;



MediaWiki API:Query = https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query

Comment: And where is "Monte Viso" coming from? What I mean is, how are you getting the data from the one API to use for the other?

Comment: Are you trying to take the value returned for `poi.name` by the Google Maps API and sending that over as the `titles` value for the wikipedia query API?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that Google's APIs and Wikipedia are two completely different systems, the only common element is the physical location of the point of interest.

First, use the Google Places API to get the location (lat/lon) of the POI.  See:  https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Next, use the Wikipedia "nearby" API to find the locations nearest the location provided by Google.  See:  https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Showing_nearby_wiki_information

Finally, it may be useful in practice to use an approximate ("fuzzy") string match on the location names to select the most likely result out of the nearby results provide by the Wikipedia API (which many results are returned).

Comment: I have already done it but I still have problems with some places because of their names